# Minimal calculator with Boost Spirit X3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am trying to write a minimalistic calculator example using Boost spirit X3. I find the official examples that do exactly this confusing because they seemingly use a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code to define and evaluate the AST and there are subtle syntax changes across versions of X3.

Here's some pseudo code outlining what I want to do:

```
  using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

  std::string Test("1 + (3 - 2)");

  auto first = Test.begin();
  auto last = Test.end();

  rule<class dash_expr> const dash_expr("dash_expr");
  rule<class factor_expr> const factor_expr("factor_expr");

  auto const dash_expr_def = factor_expr
                           >> *( (char_('+') >> dash_expr)
                               | (char_('-') >> dash_expr)
                               );

  auto const factor_expr_def = uint_
                             | '(' >> dash_expr >> ')'
                             ;

  BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(dash_expr, factor_expr);

  ascii::space_type space;

  bool r = phrase_parse(
      first,
      last,
      dash_expr,
      space
  );
```

First of all, this does not compile with a current version of boost because `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` causes a "expected expression" error. Additionally, how do I evaluate the resulting AST without defining a plethora of additional types and operations? Older Boost Spirit Qi examples suggest that it is possible to simply use "inline" expressions like `(char_('+') >> dash_expr) [_val += _1]`. Is this feature deprecated? How do I turn my pseudo code into a working example that outputs the correct result `2` using the least amount of additional lines of code?

Comment: "there are subtle syntax changes across versions of X3." - is that relevant? If so, can you clarify which changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** First of all, this does not compile with a current version of boost because BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE causes a "expected expression" error.

That's because registering rule definitions specializes function templates. It needs to be at namespace scope.

Fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/e3Essd8e8

> **Q.** Additionally, how do I evaluate the resulting AST without defining a plethora of additional types and operations? Older Boost Spirit Qi examples suggest that it is possible to simply use "inline" expressions like (char_('+') >> dash_expr) [_val += _1]. Is this feature deprecated?

No. It's just not implemented in X3. The semantic actions have been simplified many times and are now regular lambdas. Due to that, the compilation overhead of a Proto based DSL for semantic actions seems redundant.

> **Q.** How do I turn my pseudo code into a working example that outputs the correct result 2 using the least amount of additional lines of code?

Basically, by adding some code. I see some more things that can be simplified. I could show you a few variants.

One that may interest you is a simple header file (similar to the new Boost Lambda2 proposal) that implements the core of Boost Phoenix for X3.

### Simple Cakes First

The straight forward approach is to "just do the work". To make it less cumbersome, I'll emply a macro. I'll also implement a few more binary operators:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vGvTj3Mz8)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

using V = int32_t;

namespace Parser {
    x3::rule<struct expr, V> const   expr{"expr"};
    x3::rule<struct simple, V> const simple{"simple"};
    x3::rule<struct factor, V> const factor{"factor"};

    auto assign = [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); };
    #define BINOP(op, rhs) (x3::lit(#op) >> x3::as_parser(rhs) \
        [([](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _val(ctx) op _attr(ctx); })])

    auto simple_def = x3::double_ | '(' >> expr >> ')';

    auto factor_def = simple[assign] >>
        *(BINOP(*, factor) 
        | BINOP(/, factor) 
        | BINOP(%, factor));

    auto expr_def = factor[assign] >>
        *(BINOP(+, expr) 
        | BINOP(-, expr));

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expr, factor, simple)
} // namespace Parser

V evaluate(std::string_view text) {
    V value{};
    if (!phrase_parse(text.begin(), text.end(), Parser::expr >> x3::eoi,
                    x3::space, value))
        throw std::runtime_error("error in expression");
    return value;
}

int main() {
    for (auto expr : {
            "1 + (3 - 2)",
            "1 * 3 - 2",
            "17 % 5 - 2",
            "17 % (5 - 2)",
            "1 - 5 * 7",
            "(1 - 5) * 7",
            "((1 - 5) * 7)",
        })
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(expr) << "\t-> " << evaluate(expr) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"1 + (3 - 2)"   -> 2
"1 * 3 - 2"     -> 1
"17 % 5 - 2"    -> 0
"17 % (5 - 2)"  -> 2
"1 - 5 * 7"     -> -34
"(1 - 5) * 7"   -> -28
"((1 - 5) * 7)" -> -28
```

### Phoeni_X3.hpp

Without warranty of any kind, here's for inspiration: https://github.com/sehe/expression-parsers/tree/x3-c++17

Live demo on **[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FxO3HdJYKTlCgMsb)**:

```
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 0 ← "1 + ( 2 - 3 )"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 6.25 ← "( ( 1 + ( 2 - 3 ) + 5 ) / 2 ) ^ 2"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 14 ← "5 + ( ( 1 + 2 ) * 4 ) - 3"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 7 ← "3+4"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 11 ← "3+4*2"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 11 ← "3+(4*2)"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 14 ← "(3+4)*2"
----------------------------------------------
OUTPUT: 128 ← "2*2* 2* 2  * 2\t*2\n*2"
----------------------------------------------
Expecting ')' in "(2"
  (2
    ^--- here
----------------------------------------------
Expecting term in "(2+/"
  (2+/
     ^--- here
----------------------------------------------
Expecting term in "42*()"
  42*()
      ^--- here
----------------------------------------------
Expecting ')' in "(2*2* 2* 2  * 2\t*2\n*2"
  *2
    ^--- here
```

- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   //#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <string_view>
   #include "quote_esc.hpp"
   #include "phoeni_x3.hpp"
   namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

   namespace parsing {
   #pragma GCC diagnostic push
   #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wparentheses"

       using namespace PhoeniX3::placeholders;

       using Value = double;
       using x3::expect;
       x3::rule<struct _e, Value> expr   { "expr"   };
       x3::rule<struct _x, Value> expo   { "exponentation" };
       x3::rule<struct _t, Value> term   { "term"   };
       x3::rule<struct _f, Value> factor { "factor" };

       auto simple = x3::rule<struct _s, Value> {"simple"} 
           = x3::double_ [_val = _attr] 
           | '(' >> expect[term][_val = _attr] > ')'
           ;

       auto expo_def   = simple [_val = _attr] >> *(
                           '^' >> expect[expo] [ _val ^= _attr ]
                         )
                     ;

       auto factor_def = expo [_val = _attr] >> *(
                             '*' >> expect[factor] [_val *= _attr]
                           | '/' >> expect[factor] [_val /= _attr])
                     ;
       auto term_def = factor [_val = _attr] >> *(
                             '+' >> expect[term] [_val += _attr]
                           | '-' >> expect[term] [_val -= _attr])
                     ;

       auto expr_def = x3::skip(x3::space)[ x3::eps > term > x3::eoi ];

       BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expr, term, factor, expo)

       using expectation_failure = x3::expectation_failure<std::string_view::const_iterator>;

   #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
   }

   int main() {
       for (std::string_view text : {
               "1 + ( 2 - 3 )", //OUTPUT: 0.0
               "( ( 1 + ( 2 - 3 ) + 5 ) / 2 ) ^ 2", //OUTPUT: 6.25
               "5 + ( ( 1 + 2 ) * 4 ) - 3", //OUTPUT: 14.0
               "3+4",
               "3+4*2",
               "3+(4*2)",
               "(3+4)*2",
               "2*2* 2* 2  * 2\t*2\n*2",
               "(2",
               "(2+/",
               "42*()",
               "(2*2* 2* 2  * 2\t*2\n*2",
               })
       try {
           std::cout << "----------------------------------------------\n";
           double result;
           if (parse(text.begin(), text.end(), parsing::expr, result)) {
               std::cout << "OUTPUT: " << result << " ← " << quote_esc(text) << "\n";
           } else {
               std::cout << "Unparsed expression " << quote_esc(text) << "\n";
           }
       } catch(parsing::expectation_failure const& ef) {
           auto pos = ef.where() - text.begin();
           // isolate a line
           auto sol = text.find_last_of("\r\n", pos) + 1;
           auto eol = text.find_first_of("\r\n", pos);
           std::cout 
               << "Expecting " << ef.which() << " in " << quote_esc(text)
               << "\n  " << text.substr(sol, eol)
               << "\n  " << std::string(pos - sol, ' ') << "^--- here\n";
       }
   }
  ```
- File `phoeni_x3.hpp`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

   namespace PhoeniX3 {
       namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

       // base facilities
       void eval(void); // ADL enable

       // for instance-only operator overloads
       template <typename T>
       struct _base_type {
           using self = T;
           using base = _base_type;
           template <typename U> auto operator=(U&&) const;
           template <typename Ctx> decltype(auto) operator()(Ctx& ctx)/*&&*/ {
               return eval(ctx, self{});
           }
       };

       // placeholders
       struct _val_type  : _base_type<_val_type>  {using base::operator(); using base::operator=;};
       struct _attr_type : _base_type<_attr_type> {using base::operator(); using base::operator=;};
       template <int N>
       struct _atc_type  : _base_type<_atc_type<N>> {
           using base = _base_type<_atc_type>;
           using base::operator();
           using base::operator=;
       };

       namespace placeholders {
           _val_type    static const _val  {};
           _attr_type   static const _attr {};
           _atc_type<0> static const _1    {};
           _atc_type<1> static const _2    {};
           _atc_type<2> static const _3    {};
           _atc_type<3> static const _4    {};
           _atc_type<4> static const _5    {};
           _atc_type<5> static const _6    {};
           _atc_type<6> static const _7    {};
           _atc_type<7> static const _8    {};
           _atc_type<8> static const _9    {};
       }

       // expression types
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Op> struct BinExpr : _base_type<BinExpr<L,R,Op> > { 
           using BinExpr::base::operator(); 
           using BinExpr::base::operator=;
       };

       namespace tag {
           struct _add; struct _add_assign;
           struct _sub; struct _sub_assign;
           struct _mul; struct _mul_assign;
           struct _div; struct _div_assign;
           struct _exp; struct _exp_assign;
           struct _assign;
       }

       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_exp_assign> operator^=(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_add_assign> operator+=(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_sub_assign> operator-=(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_mul_assign> operator*=(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_div_assign> operator/=(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_exp> operator&(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_add> operator+(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_sub> operator-(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_mul> operator*(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L, typename R> BinExpr<L, R, tag::_div> operator/(L&&, R&&) { return {}; }
       template <typename L> template <typename R>
           auto _base_type<L>::operator=(R&&) const { return BinExpr<L, R, tag::_assign>{}; }

       template <typename Ctx>        auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, _val_type) { return x3::_val(ctx); }
       template <typename Ctx>        auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, _attr_type) { return x3::_attr(ctx); }
       template <typename Ctx, int N> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, _atc_type<N>) { return boost::fusion::at_c<N>(x3::_attr(ctx)); }

       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_add>)    { return eval(ctx, L{}) + eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_sub>)    { return eval(ctx, L{}) - eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_mul>)    { return eval(ctx, L{}) * eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_div>)    { return eval(ctx, L{}) / eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_exp>)    { return pow(eval(ctx, L{}), eval(ctx, R{})); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) = eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_add_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) += eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_sub_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) -= eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_mul_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) *= eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_div_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) /= eval(ctx, R{}); }
       template <typename L, typename R, typename Ctx> auto&& eval(Ctx& ctx, BinExpr<L, R, tag::_exp_assign>) { return eval(ctx, L{}) = pow(eval(ctx, L{}), eval(ctx, R{})); }
   }
  ```
- File `quote_esc.hpp`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <ostream>
   #include <iomanip>

   template <typename T>
   struct quote_esc {
       T sv;
       quote_esc(T sv):sv(std::move(sv)) {}

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, quote_esc const& esc) {
           os << '"';
           for(uint8_t ch : std::string_view(esc.sv))
               switch(ch) {
                   case '"' : os << "\\\""; break;
                   case '\r': os << "\\r";  break;
                   case '\n': os << "\\n";  break;
                   case '\b': os << "\\b";  break;
                   case '\0': os << "\\0";  break;
                   case '\t': os << "\\t";  break;
                   case '\f': os << "\\f";  break;
                   default: os << ch;
               }

           return os << '"';
       }
   };
  ```

Comment: dinner is due ; i'll be back to materialize that last option

Comment: Added two live demos. Hope this helps. In case you're interested, I made a completely C++-compatible expression parser (so it honors precedence **and** associativity rules) before: https://github.com/sehe/qi-extended-parser-evaluator/blob/master/parser.h (evolved from/in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210289/discussion-between-sehe-and-llm))